# How can I get Atom's script package to run a script from the script's current working directory?

Tags: python, atom-editor, working-directory

For background, I am using the Atom editor with the script package installed.

Within Atom, there are two projects that I normally use.

```
D:/Data_files/Git/Projects
D:/Data_files/Python/Notes
```

When I normally open atom from the terminal, I have both projects open, and for whatever reason it has the default project or something set to the Git/Projects project

The Git/Projects directory is not important, but here is what the Python directory looks like.

```
D:/Data_files/Python/Notes/
    __init__.py
    files_and_exceptions.py
    text.txt
```

Here's what `text.txt` contains

```
This is the text of text.txt
```

Here is what `files_and_exceptions.py` contains

```
import os
print(os.getcwd)
os.chdir("../../Python/Notes")
print(os.getcwd)

with open('text.txt') as hello:

    contents = hello.read()
    print(contents)
```

Which outputs when I run it using `CTRL+SHIFT+B` from the `files_and_exceptions.py` using script

```
D:/Data_files/Git/Projects
D:/Data_files/Python/Notes
This is the text of text.txt
```

So even though I'm running it from the Python/Notes directory, the current working directory is set to Git/Projects. I want `files_and_exceptions.py` to print `text.txt` without importing and changing directories when running from the file because that's how it would work when I run it normally using Python's Shell. I know I can set it by opening Atom from the directories in separate windows but that gets irritating when I'm working with multiple projects at once. Is there any way to easily change the current working directory of Atom when working between projects or modify the script package to change the current working directory to the directory of the open tab (ie: `files_and_exceptions.py`) when I run it with `CTRL+SHIFT+B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default settings, `script` uses the project directory of the first project in your Project tree. In the settings of `script`, you can change the that the project directory of your current script (or the directory your script resides in itself).

You go to settings (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), then the `Packages` tab, you search for the `script` package and the first dropdown menu is that setting.

---

If you don't want to change this, you can also have `script` run with a specific profile.

In the command palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, you search for `script: Run options` and you get a menu with some settings to start your script with. You can save those as profile and later use `script: Run with Profile` to reload.